# What does 'need genesis.json file as the only argument' mean?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, block, genesis

I am trying to create a Genesis block for an Ethereum Blockchain but the Windows Command Prompt is showing a Fatal error.

[image]

The code for the Genesis file is mentioned below-

```
{

 “config”:{

    “chainId”:777,

    “homesteadBlock”:0,

    “eip155Block”:0,

    “eip158Block”:0

},

“difficulty”:”0x400″,

“gasLimit”:”0x8000000″,

“alloc”:{}
```

}

What does 'need genesis.json file as the only argument' mean?

Comment: It means, that `init` takes only one argument, which is the path to the json file.

Answer (score 0):

1. Rename the file to genesis.json
2. There is a space in your file path. Put the entire file path in double-quotes or rename the folder to json_file or something without spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably following the same tutorial as you and here's how I did it:

1. @Exile79 answer is a correct start: when you have spaces in your path, it must be surrounded by quotes `"C:\path with spaces\file.json"`
2. There can only be one argument after `init`, so place the other flag in front.

Your result should look like this:

```
geth --identity "MyBlockchain" --datadir C:\Users\hodit\Downloads\Ethereum\MyPrivateChain \
init "D:\json file\CustomGenesis.json"
```

Please note that it also work with relative paths.