# How to fix 'need genesis.json file as the only argument'?

Tags: json, ethereum, blockchain, go-ethereum, genesis

[What does 'need genesis.json file as the only argument' mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75155806/what-does-need-genesis-json-file-as-the-only-argument-mean/75719229#75719229)

I have faced the same problem recently, and this question above is the only mention of this problem in the Internet. Below a link to my JSON file. I have no idea how to fix this error.

```
C:\Windows\system32>geth --identity "MyBlockChain" init C:\MyNetwork\MyGenesis.json --datadir C:\MyNetwork\MyPrivateChain
Fatal: need genesis.json file as the only argument
```

[screenshot of the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeug0.png)
[my JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcdYv.png)

I have tried change the JSON in different ways but nothing had worked. I also tried relocating my files to another disk but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I finally fixed it by swapping init and --datadir parts